# How to automatically select a file to FileUpload on page load?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file-upload, pageload

I want to automatically select a file on page load to my FileUpload1. I tried searching but I cant find any related instances. I want to do somethhing like this.

```
Private Sub WebForm1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    FileUpload1.setfile("D:\file\Test.Wav")
End Sub
```

Because my program is to record a sound (wav file) and it saves to a specific folder. And afterwards, I can select the recorded file and upload/save the file to the database. 
When you click button_1, it records a sound using the mic. Then you will button_2 to stop and save the recorded sound.
But what i wanted to do is after clicking the button_2, it will stop and save the recording AND asynchronously it uploads the file to the database.

Here is the code: .VB file

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Text

Partial Class Default2
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Protected Sub btnUpload_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpload.Click
    Using br As New BinaryReader(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream)

        Dim bytes As Byte() = br.ReadBytes(CInt(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream.Length))
        Dim strConnString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr").ConnectionString
        Using con As New SqlConnection(strConnString)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand()
                cmd.CommandText = "insert into tblFiles(Name, ContentType, Data) values (@Name, @ContentType, @Data)"
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContentType", "audio/mpeg3")
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", bytes)
                cmd.Connection = con
                con.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                con.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
    Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)
End Sub

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        BindGrid()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub BindGrid()
    Dim strConnString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr").ConnectionString
    Using con As New SqlConnection(strConnString)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand()
            cmd.CommandText = "select Id, Name from tblFiles"
            cmd.Connection = con
            con.Open()
            GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            GridView1.DataBind()
            con.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
<DllImport("winmm.dll")> _
Private Shared Function mciSendString(ByVal command As String, ByVal buffer As StringBuilder, ByVal bufferSize As Integer, ByVal hwndCallback As IntPtr) As Integer
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Dim i As Integer
        i = mciSendString("open new type waveaudio alias capture", Nothing, 0, 0)
        i = mciSendString("record capture", Nothing, 0, 0)
        Label1.Text = "Recording"
        Label1.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Green
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Try
        Dim i As Integer
        i = mciSendString("save capture " & "D:\file\Test.Wav", Nothing, 0, 0)
        i = mciSendString("close capture", Nothing, 0, 0)
        Label1.Text = "Idle"
        Label1.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Yellow
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try


End Sub





Private Sub WebForm1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
End Sub


End Class
```

aspx.file

```
<form runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Record" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Save" />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>

    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload"
onclick="btnUpload_Click" />

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" RowStyle-      BackColor="#A1DCF2" Font-Names = "Arial" Font-Size = "10pt"
HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White">

    <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="FileName" />
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data='dewplayer-vol.swf?mp3=File.ashx?Id=<%# Eval("Id") %>'
                width="240" height="20" id="dewplayer">
                <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
                <param name="movie" value='dewplayer-vol.swf?mp3=File.ashx?Id=<%# Eval("Id") %>'/>
            <object>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="Id" Text = "Download" DataNavigateUrlFormatString = "~/File.ashx?Id={0}" HeaderText="Download" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: What does any of this do, can you show more...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible due to security reasons. Imagine you visit a random site and it automatically starts uploading files from your local file system without your knowledge/permission.

The input type file control requires the user to select a file to upload, so there is no way you can do it programmatically.

Comment: I do not want to upload on page load, what i like to happen is just to select a specific file on page load, not upload right away, just select. @veselin

Comment: Still not possible for the same reasons.

Comment: What can you suggest to my situation?

Comment: Unfortunately nothing can be done to allow this. Maybe you can do whatever you want to do with the file during the Save process? You said you can save it on the local folder - it means you have the access to the file already, why don't you upload it / update the DB during that time?